# Can I use a command to get an Image's loaded event in Windows 8?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm using an MVVM pattern with commands passing from the View to the ViewModel. My question is, I want to change a property when an image is loaded. In ordinary code-behind I'd just attach to the Image Loaded property, but how do I do this in MVVM where the property I want to change is in the ViewModel?

Let me know if this is too vague and thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use **EventToCommand** behavior, or just handle the event and in code-behind raise the Command manually using **DoCommand.Execute(parameter);**